# Make ASP.NET MVC 5 Login Path Controller Agnostic

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Currently, we have a few areas set up in our project. We want the Login Path to be set to the default `/Account/Login` action, but while inside of an Area the login path will be:

```
/Controller/Id/Account/Login
```

To be clear, this is NOT asking for a unique login path for every controller/area. Regardless of area/controller it should route to `/Account/Login`, with no preceding controller or area.

Current app.UseCookieAuthentication code:

```
`AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider`
```

Comment: are you using the HTML helpers to create the link?

Comment: Nope. What you see is the only bit of code involved minus a timeout for the cookie being set. Once that timeout occurs it'll send you back to the 
full `/Controller/Id/Account/Login` path instead of using the root path for the site.